# mysql combined query, ids from comma separated list

Tags: mysql

I am not that familiar with mysql, so do not exactly not how sample the query correctly. I am working with wordpress and to illustrate what I would like to select please see the image below:

[image: scetch of mysqlquery]

I have the ID of one special post. I would like to get all other Posts that are connected to it in the following way:

In the `posts_meta` table can exist entries, whose `post_id` matches the given `ID`. One of these entries `meta_key` is of a certain value and the `meta_value` of that very entry is a comma separated list of `post_id`'s. I would like to Select `*` for each of Posts whose `ID` is in that comma separated list

I started with the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM prefix_posts AS a
JOIN prefix_postmeta AS b ON ( a.ID = b.post_id )
WHERE … //??
```

but I have no idea how to finish the query. How can I select the ids, to select posts in turn? I found SO answers dealing with `FIND_IN_SET`, but I do not want to test if a given ID is in the set, I the more need something like »STR_SPLIT« in a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to Select * for each of Posts whose ID is in that comma separated list

Why not using FIND_IN_SET method ?, it can help you for your problem
This query return all posts whose have id in meta_value field from meta row having your "special post id" as post_id.

```
SELECT * FROM Post a, meta b
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(a.id, b.linked)>0 AND b.post_id= $id_post;
```

Tried on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9af23/1), it seems to work.
Add a GROUP BY clause if you want avoid duplicates.

Comment: Thank you! This query does what I want: SELECT *
FROM prefix_posts AS a
INNER JOIN prefix_postmeta AS b
WHERE b.meta_key = "my_desired_meta_key"
AND FIND_IN_SET( a.ID, b.meta_value )>0
AND b.post_id = "the desired ID"